# Cómo distribuir una aplicación de consola creada en NodeJS

Tags: nodejs

estoy aprendiendo NodeJS y he creado una pequeña aplicación cli (command line interface) y ahora quiero distribuirla a mis usuarios y me surgen algunas preguntas:

1. ¿Los usuarios deben tener NodeJS instalado?
2. ¿Mi aplicativo lo debo distribuir con los fuentes o hay que compilar algún binario?

De antemano me disculpo si las preguntas son tontas, es que vengo de lenguajes donde solo compilo un exe y distribuyo de forma standalone.

Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. En general, sí, los usuarios deben tener NodeJS instalado. Hay herramientas open source que te permiten compilar tu script de NodeJS a un binario, pero no es una practica estándar. Podrías probar este: https://github.com/vercel/pkg
2. Si vas a distribuirlo como un NPM package, lo mas recomendado es compilar tu código con algún bundler como Webpack, Rollup, Parcel, ESBuild. Esto va a hacer que tu código pueda ser compatible con versiones anteriores de NodeJS al que estas usando para desarrollarlo. Si sabes que todos tus usuarios van la misma versión de NodeJS o mas nueva, entonces no necesitarías compilarlo.